# web-audio equivalent of Microphone.setSilenceLevel in ActionScript

Tags: microphone, web-audio-api

Is there a way to set a silence level in web-audio, similar to Microphone.setSilenceLevel in ActionScript? In other words, I'd like to only get an audio processing event, if the sound volume is above certain level. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in a pre-built way.  You'll have to implement a scriptprocessor and onaudioprocess that filters for this.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, that's actually what I did, namely, averaging the absolute values of the amplitudes then comparing to a predefined silence level. I just feel it would be more efficient if it's built-in.

Comment: Once Audio Workers are implemented, this won't really be so inefficient. But yes, less than ideal today.

Comment: I can't wait to see the audio worker working. By the way, is there a place to track the progress of audio worker in various browsers?